# Search for $C^{*}$ on MathSciNet

Tags: online-resources, publishing

I am trying to search on MathSciNet for an article which contains $C^*$ in its title (as in $C^*$-algebras) however I can't figure out how to get MathSciNet not to interpret the '*' as a stand in for an arbitrary sequence of characters.

Comment: I have [retagged the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1290667/revisions), The ([tag:searching]) tag is for various search algorithms studied in computer science. If somebody can come up with more suitable tags, it would be nice.

Comment: BTW I have mentioned your question in [MO chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21734199#21734199). Maybe somebody, who can answer, will notice it there.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that "searching" didn't seem to fit, but it wouldn't let me post without adding a tag and it wouldn't let me create my own tag.

Comment: As not to digress from the original question, if we need discuss tagging in more detail we can continues [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21734191#21734191). (But I do not have an idea for better tags. Maybe we can just leave it, at it is if somebody has better idea, they will retag. Correct tagging is important to help other users when searching for questions and also to get attention of experts following some particular tags. But more important thing is to get a good answer.)

Comment: You should be able to search MathSciNet using the AMS classification codes for topics and subtopics. My number theory/ quadratic forms articles are usually 11E20 and a few related codes. Just look at the bottom of the first page of some recent articles you like, or the reviews of some articles you like, and write down the most useful AMS subject codes for your interests.

Comment: I see; I was assuming you were a student: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/205835/theory-of-c-algebras-over-other-fields-than-the-complex-numbers

Comment: BTW, "C-star" in the title returns 9 matches.

Comment: And entering "C algebras" with a space in between returns 242 results.

Comment: See also http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/help/full_search_help_full.html#tex

Comment: Some users voted to close, some of them voted to leave open: http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/418260 Personally, I would prefer to leave this question open.

Comment: Probably it should be mentioned that the help does not contain any solution for this: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/help/full_search_help_full.html (Unless I have overlooked it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have emailed technical support at MathSciNet. Unfortunately they do not know how to search for a string containing a *, as * is interpreted as a wild card. However, if you know the word before and after the * then you can use the proximity search tool adjN which is a stand in for at most N-1 words.

For example, searching for "C adj2 algebra" will find "$C^*$-algebra", as well as "l.m.c. algebras".